# How to set cursor position using "__asm" function in "C++"?

Tags: c++, assembly

I have tried this code:

```
int main()
{
    __asm ("mov %dl, 0"); // Cursor X Position
    __asm ("mov %dh, 0"); // Cursor Y Position
    __asm ("mov %ah, 2"); // Set Cursor
    __asm ("mov %bh, 0"); // Page Number
    __asm ("int $0x10"); // Interrupt

    return 0;
}
```

But I get this output:

> Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I'm using "Code::Blocks" with "GNU GCC Compiler".

Comment: Which OS and CPU architecture are you trying to run this on?

Comment: Windows 10 - Intel i7 64-bit.

Comment: It seems you're attempting to do some DOS programming in a Windows environment. That won't work very well. What resource are you using to learn about "cursor" position?

Comment: Then you should probably use the appropriate Windows API function instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition

Comment: Is there any other ways to set cursor position in C/C++ before it gets to Windows?

Comment: No, ISO C++ doesn't have a cursor. That's a feature of the Windows terminal you're running in.  (Or for a different OS, a feature of the terminal there.)  Also, even for DOS this GNU C inline asm would be unsafe: you modify registers without telling the compiler about it.  (But never mind that because inline asm isn't going to be useful for this in a Windows program.)

Comment: @1999xCoder -- If you got that code from a book, that book probably is dog-eared, with yellowing pages.  The point is that this type of coding was for an OS that had long since passed on.